# how to import a default exported graphql query in angular 12?

Tags: angular, graphql, angular12, apollo-angular

I have an angular 12 project and i wanna use graphql with apollo-angular. i create a category.js file with the codes below:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const CATEGORIES_QUERY = gql`
query Categories {
    categories {
        id
        name
    }
}
`;

export default CATEGORIES_QUERY;
```

and in my component.ts i wanna import this js file:

```
import CATEGORIES_QUERY from "../apollo/queries/category/categories";
```

but i got the error below:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '../apollo/queries/category/categories'. 
'c:/Users/Diba Computer/vscode/blog- 
strapi/frontend/src/app/apollo/queries/category/categories.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add the following to `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  "allowJs": true,
  "checkJs": false,
    ...
  }
}
```

This prevents typescript from applying module types to imported javascript.